# How to install missing wx module on Python 2.5?

Tags: python, windows, wxpython, python-2.5

I have developped a tool under `python 2.5` and can't upgrade to a newer `python` version as I need to use an API developped under `python 2.5` as well.

I recently tried my tool under another machine and it seems it hasn't `wx` module installed as you can see below:

```
>>> import wx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named wx
```

So I searched for the [wxpython source](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wxPython/4.0.0b1). However once I tried to install the source with:

```
D:\tmp\wxPython-4.0.0b2>c:\Python25\python.exe setup.py install
```

I got following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "setup.py", line 15, in
>   
>       from setuptools                     import setup, find_packages ImportError: No module named setuptools

I can't either install `whl` files as I don't have `pip`.

So, **how can I install `wxpython` for `python 2.5` under `Windows`**?

Is there any executable there in the web that I couldn't find? May there be a workaround by copying the `wx` module from a `python` directory from another computer?

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/projects/wxpython/files/wxPython/2.5.4.1/         Download from sourceforge

Comment: @PatrickONeill which link do you think I should use? If you post as answer I would be glad to upvote and/or accept your answer.

Comment: try this one:https://sourceforge.net/projects/wxpython/files/wxPython/2.7.1.2/wxPython2.7-win32-unicode-2.7.1.2-py25.exe/download

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I had to install `wxpython 2.7.2.0` I finally got it from [wxPython2.7-win32-ansi-2.7.2.0-py25.exe](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wxpython/files/wxPython/2.7.2.0/wxPython2.7-win32-ansi-2.7.2.0-py25.exe/download).

As stated in Patrick's comment all wxpython executables for any version are under https://sourceforge.net/projects/wxpython/files/wxPython/